# Display problems on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, tearing

My Setup:
GPU: EVGA GTX 660
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
GPU driver: Nvidia bianary driver - version 364.19 from nvidia-364 (open source)
Monitor configuration: VHV, two vertical 1920x1080 screens on the sides of a 4k horizontal screen in the middle.

Hello,
I am having two annoying problems with my Display
     1. The first and most problematic for me is that in the middle of the 4k screen, when i watch a movie or move a window back and forth, there is a horizontal tear going from side to side right in the middle of the screen.
     2. When my computer wakes up from sleep mode the screen configuration is incorrect, only the two side monitors are on and they are no longer rotated, I can usually fix this by redoing the config, or relogging, but as you can imagine it is quite frustrating to do multiple times a day.

I apologize in advance, I'm good with computers, but I just switched over from Windows so I do not know Linux very well yet. I may be a bit slow to understand your instructions because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the original driver from nvidia?

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.44/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run

I had a past experience with this, and install not the EVGA driver, but the GeForce driver. If this if you did before.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too but I haven't been able to get it to run, Ive come across two errors, when I try to install it it tells me something along the lines of "you appear to be running an x server, can not install" Then I followed the directions on a website to fix that error and the next error I got was along the lines of "an nvidia module "nvidia" appears to already be loaded." which I have not been able to get past

Comment: Try this sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: That... just caused some problems.... now I can only set my side screens to 1024x768 and my 4k screen is at 480P and higher resolution options are not available. also all 3 screens are overlapping eachother

Comment: Whatis shown on the ubuntu config "screens" or "Monitor" (Dont know how it is shown on english) It detects all your 3 monitors...can you make changes over that config window?

Comment: I unchecked the mirror option, but it is still mirrored, this is what im looking at http://imgur.com/a/Leapl can't turn the resolution up. On a side note, im getting rather good at using a sideways monitor

Comment: I could do a quick reinstall of ubuntu if you know a better build

Comment: Yeah you could try that or you can try to uninstall x server from software center, and then try the original driver from nvidia. Let me know how works.

Comment: Just finished reinstall,  figured something interesting out, the screen tearing goes away if I have my monitors set to horizontal. not sure why though. the good news is that ubuntu automatically downloaded the proprietary nvidia driver

Comment: So..can you configured it on the way you wanted?

Comment: nope, same boat as before, now just with nvidia drivers. i did find out that it seems to be related to my side monitorrs being rotated, no screen tear when they are not rotated